# hex representation for integers in Golang

Tags: go, hex

Can't understand how Go converts integers to hex

when I run this code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    d := -12345
    hex := fmt.Sprintf("%X", d)
    fmt.Println(hex)
}
```

I see result `-3039`, but I expect to see `cfc7`, because go uses Two’s-Complement representation
And how can I get a right answer in the output?

Answer (score -1):

You are passing in an `int`, which is signed. Pass an unsigned in:

```
    hex := fmt.Sprintf("%X", d)
```

This will print FFFFFFFFFFFFCFC7